# How to pass params to one component with routerLink?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-routing

I ran into impossibility to pass/get params with routerLink.

**I have app.component.ts/html:**

```
 <header></header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer class="flux-container">
  ...
  <a routerLink="/info/1" routerLinkActive="active">Privacy Policy</a>
  <a routerLink="/info/2" routerLinkActive="active">Terms & Conditions</a>
  ...
</footer>
```

**and info.component.ts:**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-info',
  templateUrl: './info.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./info.component.css']
})
export class InfoComponent implements OnInit {
  order : number;
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.order = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id;
    console.log('this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params ', this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params);
  }
}
```

**routing.ts**

```js
{
    path         : 'info/:id',
    canActivate  : [AccountGuard, AppEnter],
    pathMatch    : 'full',
    component    : InfoComponent
  },
```

**by cliking /info/1 or /info/2**
i can't get this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id and use it, only by refresh page. Just simple move.

help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
order$: Observable<string>;

this.order$ = this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(map(resp => resp.get("id")));
```